# NoClassDefFoundError - GenTraversableOnce$class with Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I am getting following error while using Akka. I suspect it could be because of incompatible Akka version but I do not know which one to use.

build.sbt

```
name := "Example"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.2-M1"
```

Error

```
>sbt run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Manu\.sbt\0.13\plugins
[info] Set current project to Example (in build file:/C:/Users/Manu/Documents/manu/programs/scala/from_book/)
[info] Running Upper
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
        at akka.util.Collections$EmptyImmutableSeq$.<init>(Collections.scala:15)
```

Comment: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.4" % Test
)
` worked for me but I am wondering if there is a way to find compatibility of versions of Akka and Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix `_2.10` in `akka-actor_2.10` indicates you want the version for Scala 2.10, which does not match your scala version above (2.11).

If you want to use Scala 2.11, the latest version of Akka would be

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.5.4"
```

You can see all the versions here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11